# Encoding issue ü to Ã¼ in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, encoding

I am facing an encoding issue. The char ü will be Ã¼ after i parse the key-value pairs from the header.

My application(Spring Boot Java App) is receiving data from another webserver. The data on the first webserver is printed out correctly. If I grab these data with @RequestHeader some signs are not decoded correctly.

Example: ü will be Ã¼

I tried to configure that every part is using UTF-8 as encoding.

**html/jsp from my app**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Apache Config

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Spring Boot application.properties

```
# Encoding
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=false
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
spring.banner.charset=UTF-8
spring.mandatory-file-encoding=UTF-8
```

If I print the header on the spring boot app I see already the wrong chars.

How I grab the data from the header.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myForm", produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
public String processForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("myEntity") MyEntity theEntity,
        BindingResult theBindingResult,
        Model theModel,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
        @RequestHeader(required = false, value = "username") String username,
        @RequestHeader(required = false, value = "firstname") String firstname,
        @RequestHeader(required = false, value = "lastname") String lastname,
        @RequestHeader(required = false, value = "mail") String email,
        @RequestHeader(required = false, value = "company") String company) {
```

Comment: Probably we'll need to see the code that does the reading and printing of the text in question.

Comment: So the other server evidently sends UTF-8, but the **reading** assumes the data is in ISO-8859-1 (the HTTP default). `consumes = "...; charset=UTF-8"`

Comment: What happens if you run the spring boot app with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` as a startup VM parameter? You cannot put this value in a property file - it must go into the JVM startup (command line)

Comment: What happens if you set `spring.http.encoding.force` to `true`?

Comment: I already tried to set `spring.http.encoding.force` to `true` but without any difference

Comment: It seems that somewhere in my code the header information is interpreted with the charset ISO-8859-1 but I cant figure it out where.

Comment: And now we shall ask our magic eightball and tell you what it said?